# spreadsheets.get method not returning any actual value, just format

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So I am trying to get a whole sheets at one bacause I otherwise get too many request and API is blocking me. I have copied code on [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get).  Unfortunately it basicly just return me things like fontSize , foregroundColor,foregroundColor , italic , strikethrough , underline.
It says if it's true or not or the characteristics. I have remove credentials=None because it created errors.
Hope you can help me. IF you have others method to limit API request you can always tell me. I'm new to python also.

```
    #from googleapiclient import discovery

# TODO: Change placeholder below to generate authentication credentials. See
# https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample
#
# Authorize using one of the following scopes:
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'


service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

# The spreadsheet to request.
spreadsheet_id = '1MJSV4j8iT5zoDTKIHfsYmFdmXFiP932UNbaP_t0rakw'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# The ranges to retrieve from the spreadsheet.
ranges = ['Mobile!A1-S200']  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# True if grid data should be returned.
# This parameter is ignored if a field mask was set in the request.
include_grid_data = True  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

request = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=ranges, includeGridData=include_grid_data)
response = request.execute()

# TODO: Change code below to process the `response` dict:
pprint(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- Your goal is `So I am trying to get a whole sheets at one because I otherwise get too many request and API is blocking me.`.

  - In this case, I cannot understand whether you want to retrieve all cell values from all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet or you want to retrieve all data from all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet as JSON data.
  - So, I would like to propose above 2 patterns.
- You have already been able to get values from Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for python.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, all cell values from all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet are retrieved using the methods of "spreadsheets.get" and "spreadsheets.values.batchGet".

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheet_id = '###'  # Please set Spreadsheet ID.

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# 1. Retrieve the title of all sheets.
fields = 'sheets(properties(title))'
res1 = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, fields=fields).execute()

# 2. Retrieve all values from all sheets.
ranges = [e['properties']['title'] for e in res1['sheets']]
res2 = service.spreadsheets().values().batchGet(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=ranges).execute()
print(res2)
```

- In this script, at first, all sheet titles are retrieved and all values from all sheets are retrieved using the sheet titles.
- If you want to retrieve the values from the specific sheets, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    ranges = ['Sheet1']
    res = service.spreadsheets().values().batchGet(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=ranges).execute()
    print(res)
  ```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, all data from all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet is retrieved as JSON data using the method of "spreadsheets.get".

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheet_id = '###'  # Please set Spreadsheet ID.

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# 1. Retrieve data from all sheets.
fields = 'sheets'
res = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, fields=fields).execute()
print(res)
```

- In this script, `sheets` is used for `fields` in order to retrieve all data from all sheets. The response value is a JSON data.
- If you want to retrieve the data from the specific sheets, please use `ranges` as follows.

  ```
    fields = 'sheets'
    ranges = ['Sheet1']
    res = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=ranges, fields=fields).execute()
    print(res)
  ```

### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)

Comment: I have run your first method and it worked nicely. However with the second method, it just return me format (things like that : 'padding' and italic=false) instead of actual values.Is there any advantage to json ?

Comment: @TechFan_Theo Thank you for replying. From `I have run your first method and it worked nicely.`, I could understand that my proposal script was useful for your situation. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about `However with the second method, it just return me format (things like that : 'padding' and italic=false) instead of actual values.Is there any advantage to json ?`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By this, I would like to modify my proposed script. By the way, was your question resolved by the sample of pattern1?

Comment: my goal is to select rows that have certain characteristics (I have a G sheets with phone, Internet subsciption). However if I ask the Api every row that match my charasteristics, it send too much request and the API block me aftter 1000request/100 seconds. So I'm now trying to first extract the google sheets and then selecting the rows that match my criterias. . I'm not asking you to do that here just the best method to do that afterward. If you don't know I  will just do it with patern 1 then. FYI The end goal is to do a subscription comparator

Comment: Just noticed that the first method basically return csv-like text. I am not opposed to that but not having all the formating that I Put in G sheets annoys me, I would like to keep it.

Comment: @TechFan_Theo Thank you for replying. At the pattern 1, the cell values are retrieved as 2 dimensional array. At the pattern 2, the cell values are retrieved as the array of JSON object. From `I'm now trying to first extract the google sheets and then selecting the rows that match my criterias.`, in this case, I thought that the pattern 1 might be suitable. When the values are 2 dimensional array, for example, this can be also directly used for the method of values.update in Sheets API. But if my understanding of your replying is not correct, I apologize.

Comment: the json unfortunately doesn't get me any values (here is a screenshot : https://imgur.com/a/x3wWy2p) I would like to have both values and formating.

Comment: @TechFan_Theo Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from `both values and formating`, I cannot understand about your detail goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. Can you provide the sample values you expect? Because the values from `service.spreadsheets().get()` include "both values and formating". If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to try to understand about your current issue. Can you cooperate to resolve your issue?

Comment: to be fair I don't really know what I am exactly looking for but what I do know is that I am looking to keep the formating that is on my sheets to my result.

Comment: @TechFan_Theo Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about it. In order to correctly understand about it, can you provide the sample values you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: No need to apologise. I would close this thread as I have done another post asking for help on the broader goal. The broader goal is to do a phone subscription comparator. To be more practical, the user would need to enters criterias such as Prices and GB of Data, and it would return subscription (rows) that match it's criterias.

Comment: @TechFan_Theo Thank you for replying. I apologize that I cannot understand about the detail of your goal from your replying comments. I would like to study more and more.